# How to get proper offset address in structure

Tags: c, memory, struct, structure

I am defining all registers under single structure and accessing its size as offset as shown below .

```
typedef struct _REG_STRUC {
UINT32      E1000_CTRL     // 0x00000       
UINT32      E1000_CTRL_DUP  //0x00004  
UINT32 E1000_STATUS //0x00008  
UINT32 E1000_EERD   //0x00014  
UINT32 E1000_CTRL_EXT   //0x00018   
UINT32 E1000_FLA    //0x0001C  
UINT32 dummy[3] //0x00020-0x00028   
UINT32 E1000_FCAH    //0x0002C  
}*REGP;
```

As u can see above I have inserted a dummy array  to skip 12 bytes .If i skip those 12 bytes only i am getting the exact memory location of  E1000_FCAH register . As per my knowledge it's a waste of memory . How to overcome this . Knowledge me on this

**Edit** : After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182472/memory-allocation-for-structures-elements) i got to know about padding concept . I want to access the reg E100_FCAH by using it as offset address . So to avoid wrong fetch(due to gap of 12bytes) i have used dummy array of size 12 bytes .

Comment: Not put the dummy array there? Otherwise your question is quite unclear. And how does it skip 12 bits?

Comment: Ty Sami  ... It is bytes not bits..Have u got my question now...Is it clear?

Comment: you can assign the value to each variable of the structure separately, like REGP-> E1000_CTRL = <some_value> , REGP->E1000_CTRL_DUP = <some_value>...etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not clear. Where do you get the values? What is the use of this structure? Why do you want to not waste 12 bytes of memory? Is it used thousands of times somewhere so it matters?

Comment: and if you are assigning the value to REGP using single call then you are better off using dummy variable.

Comment: To get the exact memory location of register i am skipping those bytes by using dummy array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that the struct you're presenting is meant to be overlaid on some existing memory or device mapping, we cannot really change it.  But if your point is that you want to save memory when copying this data, you can certainly "clone" the structure without the unnecessary `dummy` (and any other unnecessary members), and copy it:

```
typedef struct _PACKED_STRUC {
UINT32      E1000_CTRL     // 0x00000       
UINT32      E1000_CTRL_DUP  //0x00004  
UINT32 E1000_STATUS //0x00008  
UINT32 E1000_EERD   //0x00014  
UINT32 E1000_CTRL_EXT   //0x00018   
UINT32 E1000_FLA    //0x0001C
UINT32 E1000_FCAH    //0x0002C  
}*PACKEDP;

void copy_from_raw(REGP rawp, PACKEDP outp) {
    outp->E1000_CTRL = rawp->E1000_CTRL;
    // etc.
}
```