# Is it safe to expect there will be no padding between members?

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer, padding

As stated by the C11 draft, I can assure these two:

1. > ... There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, **but not at its beginning**.
2. > There may be unnamed padding **at the end of a structure or union**.

However, it's ambiguous to me if a padding between any two members is acceptable. **It's because, by saying the second paragraph, the standard seems to insinuate the padding is only possible at the end of a structure or union.** For example, assuming `int` occupies 4 bytes here,

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s {
    char c;
    int a;
};

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(struct s));
    return 0;
}
```

am I safe to conclude that there would be no padding between `c` and `a`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [memory allocation for structures elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182472/memory-allocation-for-structures-elements)

Comment: @user694733 **I don't think so.** I'm reasoning with the standard, there's the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot conclude that there would be no padding between members.

The first quote says,

> ... There may be unnamed padding **within a structure object**, but not at its beginning.

Which makes clear that there can be padding within the members. It was actually not clear about what happens *at the end*. So, to clear that up, the second quote says

> *There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.*

This **does not** say, there cannot be padding between members. It's not **only** at end, it may, or may not be there, based on existing member alignment.

Comment: Why did the standard **only** talk about the possible padding at the end...? I'm confused.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: quoting your quote "There may be unnamed padding **within a structure** object.

Comment: @Kay Well, I thought that—what they mean by "within a structure"—was covered by the second quote.

Comment: If we stick to the literal meaning, it seems you're right. It's irony. For the portability, I cannot use the most fundamental constructs (including bit-fields) designed for the sake of programmers. Then, I would do the same thing as the assembly language would do.

Comment: @Il-seobBae For portability, you can't even use raw `int` values.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I mean the portability of a source code (not a binary file) for "bit packing".

Comment: @Il-seobBae *I mean portability for "bit packing".* Why would you even expect things like structure layout to be portable in any way?  Different implementations not only have different alignment requirements, they can have different *sizes* for the same data types.  They can even have a different number of bits per byte.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It would be great if the language (the standard) supports some constructs for fixed layout. The rest is the compiler's job.

Comment: @Il-seobBae are you looking for fixed-width data types? They are already there, AFAIK.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Of course, I know that. However, even with those types, we need to do bit-wise operations for bit-packing. What I want a (high-level) programming language to be, along with conveniently accessing small bits with a name, the alignment is guaranteed to be fixed. If the standard does that, the compiler has to comply with these requirements.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm not saying all the objects in a language should get a fixed alignment. It would be nice if the language supports it when the programmer wants it. The portable bit-packing in c is just like an assembly code... Anyway, it's just my opinion.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Structure layouts cannot be presumed to be portable between vastly different architectures, but quality compilers for similar architectures should lay out structures the same way in the absence of a compelling reason to do otherwise.  The Standard defers to implementers' judgments since it makes no effort to define how a *quality* implementation behave, nor what characteristics would make a compiler suitable or unsuitable for any purpose beyond those that can be effectively served by all architectures, including the most obscure ones.

Comment: @supercat "Quality compiler"?  That's entirely subjective.  How much experience do you have on non-x86 architectures where alignment differences can have significant performance impacts?  Where *the same compiler* can produce differently-aligned versions of the same structure based nothing more than different optimization options?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I said "in the absence of a compelling reason to do otherwise".  What reasons are compelling would be a matter of implementer's judgment, but an implementer who is seeking to produce a quality product should seek to exercise good judgment.  If there are four implementations on a platform that all use the same layout rules, a compiler which uses arbitrarily-different rules *for no discernible reason* should be viewed as lower quality than one which matches the others, but a quality compiler might use different behavior *if it documents a compelling reason for the difference*.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It's unfortunate that the Standard doesn't specify any predefined macros that would indicate whether an implementation consistently uses "common" layout rules (place all objects at the first location satisfying alignment (for arrays, the first location satisfying member alignment).  Although other layouts might be more efficient on some platforms, it's useful to be able to have functions that can e.g. operate upon any structure of the form `struct {size_t size; thing_type  items[someNumber];}`.  Flexible array members are only useful for objects of heap duration...

Comment: ...but on the 99% of implementations where the offset of `items` would be unaffected by its size, it should be easy to have a function operate on structures of that form without the compiler having to know or care about the exact type involved.  Such constructs certainly used to be commonplace and not even remotely controversial and there's no reason the language should devolve to make them unusable.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot assume there will be no padding between fields of the same structure.  By the way, your example will have most probably some padding between the two fields of your struct:

```
struct s {
    char c;
    /* most probably, you'll get padding here */
    int a;
};
```

the reason for that is that you'll need to have the access to the `a` field aligned with some architecture constraint (for example a  multiple of `sizeof int` address).  Intel processors are notably not requiring this, but most of other architectures force a misalignment to raise some kind of exception (you'll see `SIGBUS` signal on unix, tipically) that results in a program error. See [Is it guaranteed that array elements in C will be stored consecutively, with no padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766161/is-it-guaranteed-that-array-elements-in-c-will-be-stored-consecutively-with-no/43797780#43797780) and you'll get some idea of the problem behind.

Anyway, intel processors solve the problem by doing *two* external bus requests for each misaligned `int`, and discarding the unneeded data.  The reason is that for a processor with a wordsize of four bytes (typicall in 32bit architectures) there are no A0 and A1 address lines (they have four bus-slice-enable lines, or nothing at all) and they access the bus to read the whole word and then discard the data they don't need.  A four bytes `int` value misaligned would have part of the value in one address and the rest in the next/previous address.  Other architectures just fire a trap and allow the operating system to get in charge of this.