# Is it guaranteed that array elements in C will be stored consecutively, with no padding?

Tags: c, arrays, padding, memory-alignment, pointer-arithmetic

In other words: is it guaranteed that if I have an array allocated this way:

```
void *arr = calloc(nmemb, sizeof(some_type))
```

Then `elta`, `eltb`, `eltc` will all point to the same location in memory, which will be the second element of type `some_type` of this array?

```
some_type *elta = &((some_type*)arr)[1];
some_type *eltb = ((some_type*)arr)+1;
some_type *eltc = (char*)arr+sizeof(some_type);
```

The reason I’m asking this is because I’m trying to do a “container” in C, and if this doesn’t hold then I’m out of ideas how to return a pointer to any other element than the first one.

Comment: why would there be some padding? when you `malloc(nmemb * sizeof(some_type))` you don't have padding.

Comment: Where is array here?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I dunno. But I prefer to ask rather than run into UB.

Comment: Nope , my error.  I was considering `some_type*` as the type and not `some_type`.  No problem with this.

Comment: `((some_type*)arr)++` You can't post-increment an rvalue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So I suppose I could as well ask if `malloc(nmemb * sizeof(some_type))` is equivalent to `calloc(nmemb, sizeof(some_type))` and thus an appropriate way to allocate spce for an array.

Comment: When you use pointer variables, arr[i] is the same as *(arr + i).

Comment: @ephemient Sure thing, fixed, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can C arrays contain padding in between elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066681/can-c-arrays-contain-padding-in-between-elements)

Comment: Actually this is a good question, since the it's tricky to find a proper standard reference.

Comment: Asking again, __where is the array here__?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I intend `arr` to be the array, which would normally be declared as `some_type *arr = calloc(nmemb, sizeof(some_type))`, but must be declared as `void*` instead, if the “container” is to be type-agnostic. But tbh when I saw your comment for the first time, I though you were trying to tell me I was simply doing some senseless shit… Sorry if I misinterpreted this.

Comment: @gaazkam a pointer is not an array, be aware. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Right, strictly speaking you’re of course right :)

Comment: Padding or not you can get the address of any element by doing `&(arr[i])`. While saying this I do not want to imply that there *can* be padding. There is **no** padding between array elements.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya `you can get the address of any element by doing &(arr[i])` AFAIK I can do this only if `arr` is of correct pointer type, if it’s `void*`, then I can’t get the addres of the third element of type `some_type` by writing `&(arr[2])`.

Comment: @gaazkam, assuming you know the type of the contained element (I read you are implementing a container), you can cast `void*` to `T*` and then do the above mentioned. Anyway you have to cast the `void*` to something (usually char*) before adding anything. Since pointer arithmetic on `void*` is UB.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thank you for your remark. The container code does not know the type, only the `sizeof()` of the type. Only the code using the container knows the type.

Comment: @gaazkam in that case, casting to `unsigned char*` and adding multiples of sizeof is your only option.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Many thanks. However, why did you mention `unsigned char*` and not `char*`? Why does it matter?

Comment: @gaazkam No particular reason. Both are valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed. *If* padding bytes are added, they are added *within* `struct some_type`, but not in between two array elements.

E. g.:

```
struct S
{
    int n;
    short s;

// this is just for illustration WHERE byte padding (typically) would occur!!!
#if BYTE_ALIGNMENT >= 4
    unsigned char : 0;
    unsigned char : 0;
#endif
};
struct S s[2];
size_t d = (char*)(s + 1) - (char*)s;
```

With byte alignment adjusted to 4 or 8 (or even larger powers of 2), this struct will have size of 8 and d will be equally 8, with byte alignment set to 1 or 2, the struct will have size of 6 just as will be d...

Note: This is not the only place where padding bytes can occur: If you switched members `n` and `s`, padding bytes would be needed in between `s` and `n` to get `n` correctly aligned. On the other hand, no padding bytes would be necessary after n any more as the structure size would assure correct alignment already.

Referring to the standard: C11, 6.2.5.20:

> An array type describes a **contiguously allocated** nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the element type. 36) Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number of elements in the array. [...]

(Highlighting by me!).

Comment: What is this syntax: `unsigned char : 8;` ? I’ve never seen such a syntax before.

Comment: What is `BYTE_ALIGNMENT`? Bytes are mever aligned to anything else than bytes, i.e. `1`. And there is not necessarily padding between a `short` and an unsigned char` - typically there is none.

Comment: @gaazkam This is a [bit-field](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm). I used it to be able to add anonymous bytes...

Comment: @Olaf Well, see my comment: "this is just for illustration WHERE byte padding would occur" -- the macro does not exist, of course, it shall represent the compiler settings, and the unsigned char bit fields were thought to *represent* the padding bytes. Wasn't that obvious?

Comment: @Aconcagua: Padding bytes can occur after **any** field in a structure. There is no guarantee for a specific layout. It depends on the implementation and ABI of the target platform. Also note that C99 is **not the C standard**. It has been canceled 6 years ago with the release of C11.

Comment: @Olaf Above was just one single example, and the important point was only that padding occurs *within* the struct. Question was actually not about how alignment is realised in struct layout anyway. -- Standard is easy, though, just exchanging the ciphers (paragraph and text exactly the same in both...).

Comment: @Olaf Admitted - correct alignment *could* be realised, too, by inserting the padding bytes in between n and s members (in this case). Never saw a compiler doing this, though...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Because it does not make sense and would complicate the compiler without any benefit (and because ABIs state different). But that's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Data alignment is a complex matter, as illustrated by the following example (that you can even draw to make your own experiments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct A {  /* no padding */
    char a[3];
};
struct B {
    int  a;
    char b[3];
    /* one byte of padding (in 32bit arch) added here */
};
struct C {  /* no padding again */
    char a[4];
    char b[3];
};

struct D {
    char a[3];
    /* one byte of padding to ensure alignment of next field */
    int  b;
    char c[3];
    /* one byte of padding to ensure alignment of whole struct in arrays */
}

#define P(X) printf("sizeof struct %s == %ld\n", #X, sizeof (struct X))
int main()
{
    P(A);
    P(B);
    P(C);
    P(D);
} /* main */
```

As you see, the required alignment (1 byte) of the `struct A` type is allowing to place it anywhere in memory and determines that no padding bytes are necessary to determine the `sizeof` value.

In the second example, we introduced an `int` value, which forces the whole `struct` to be word aligned (so an int is accessible in a properly aligned memory address) so this time, the compiler has padded (at the end of the structure) for extra bytes, so any array type of the specified type gets correctly aligned, and its `int` field is accessed at a valid address.

In the third example, I illustrate that the effect of the padding in the second example is due to the `int` field present in the struct, as the third example has a same size field, but this time a non requiring alignment field, so no padding has been inserted, as all the individual data types inside need alignment of 1.

The output (on my system, a MAC OSX system) is:

```
sizeof struct A == 3
sizeof struct B == 8
sizeof struct C == 7
sizeof struct D == 12
```